# next option jquery

Tags: jquery

trying to select next option drop down list by using a id identifier, but to no avail

here is the code

```
$('#chapter option:selected', 'select').removeAttr('selected').next('option').attr('selected', 'selected')
```

Comment: How does your markup look like? Either #chapter or 'select' is redundant here, meaning that either you want to change this on *all* selects, or on only one specific select.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is your friend!

Comment: @Jakub Thanks for the link I will definitely use this ¬_¬

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume `#chapter` is the `<select>` or one of its ancestors.

If that's the case, remove the context argument.

```
$('#chapter option:selected').removeAttr('selected')
              .next('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

The way you had it, you were effectively doing this:

```
$('select').find('#chapter option:selected').removeAttr(...
```

...which is looking for an element *inside* the `<select>` that has an `option:selected` descending from an elelent with the `chapter` ID.

---

**EDIT:** This answer was focused merely  on why the selection wasn't working. It would be better to accomplish the ultimate task using the method in [@Andy E's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335837/next-option-jquery/4336169#4336169).

I'd recommend that one as the Accepted answer.

Comment: I know it's the OP's original code but removing the `selected` attribute is unnecessary if you're setting it on a different option element.

Comment: @Andy E - Just getting back to this. Good point. I was more focused on why the selection wasn't working.

Answer (score 5):

It's unnecessary to remove the `selected` attribute from an `<option>` element when you're adding it to one of its siblings, unless the `<select>` element has the *multiple* attribute.

Assuming [patrick dw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335837/next-option-jquery/4335865#4335865) is correct (and it is because you've accepted it), you could refactor this code into something so much more efficient by taking DOM back to its roots:

```
$("#chapter")[0].selectedIndex++;
```

Not to mention the precious bytes you're saving with shorter code.

Comment: Precious bytes. They are important `$("#chapter")[0].selectedIndex++`

Comment: +1 This would be the way to go for what OP is ultimately trying to achieve.